# Create Sequence in Pro*c language

Tags: c, plsql, proc

I am learning Pro*c language. I am trying to create a sequence. But I am not getting which keyword to use as when we create a cursor then we use declare with it as

```
    EXEC SQL DECLARE CUR_NAME CURSOR FOR <<SELECT STMT>>.
```

So is there any way to create a sequence in Pro*C?

I tried this way using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
 EXEC SQL  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE "create sequence seq1 minvalue 1 maxvalue 9999 start with 1 increment by 1";
 EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
```

But it's not reflecting in my database.The sequence is not created in it.

Comment: Can CURSORS can be declared as objects? I've only ever used them as variables between **BEGIN DECLARE** and **END DECLARE**.  Then open and select them.

Comment: Yes It can be. I used it as this way.

Comment: Pro*C is not a language on its own right, but a pre-compiler for C by Oracle. And that has nothing to do with the "embedded" tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution by 2 ways we can do it:

1st is :

```
 EXEC SQL create sequence seq1 minvalue 1 maxvalue 9999 start with 1 increment by 1;
 EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
```

2nd :

```
 EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create sequence seq1 minvalue 1 maxvalue 9999 start with 1 increment by 1';
 EXEC SQL COMMIT WORK RELEASE;
```